# Can't connect to RDS from local machine after modifying size

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Any idea why I can’t connect to an RDS instance after modifying it? Both my local macs can no longer connect to the RDS instance after I modified it this morning, but my EC2 instance can connect just fine. I set the IP Inbound / Outbound to allow all, what else could I be missing? My driver still works because I can still connect to other database.

Comment: Did you also change the subnet or VPC by mistake? Is it in a private subnet of the VPC?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! It was a DNS caching issue, but clearing my cache didn't fix it. To verify it was a DNS issue, I ran:

```
dig <host-name>
dig 8.8.8.8 <host-name>
```

The responses were different. So I edited my computer network settings by going to System Preferences > Network > YOUR NETWORK INTERFACE, PROBABLY "Wi-Fi" > Advanced > DNS and changing it to 8.8.8.8